# c# SQL Statement Incorrect syntax near '.'

Tags: c#, asp.net

This code wasn't working as it should as it was showing all ads whatever if the approv= YES or NO. Where it is supposed to check into UserInfo if the user has YES in column 'approv' then show his ads otherwise don't show. So I tried to fix it but now I have put myself in more trouble as I am getting the error message as in my post title `incorrect syntax near '.'`

```
SqlDataAdapter dashowadsoneLogo = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT AD.[AdsID], AD.[Country], AD.[State], AD.[City], AD.[AdsTit], SUBSTRING([AdsDesc],1,50) as AD.AdsDesc,
                  AD.[AdsPrice], AD.[Section], AD.[Category], AD.[Img1], AD.[AdsDate], I.[approv] FROM [ads] as AD JOIN UserInfo as I ON  AD.[Country] = @Location and I.[approv]='YES' ORDER BY AD.[AdsDate] DESC", cs);
```

Comment: You missed the alias AD in (SUBSTRING([AD.AdsDesc],1,50) as AD.AdsDesc)

Comment: This is really a question about SQL and not C#, should change the tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the alias **AD** in your code.

Try This Code :

```
SqlDataAdapter dashowadsoneLogo = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT AD.[AdsID], AD.[Country], AD.[State], AD.[City], AD.[AdsTit], SUBSTRING([AD.AdsDesc],1,50) as AD.AdsDesc,
              AD.[AdsPrice], AD.[Section], AD.[Category], AD.[Img1], AD.[AdsDate], I.[approv] FROM [ads] as AD JOIN UserInfo as I ON  AD.[Country] = @Location and I.[approv]='YES' ORDER BY AD.[AdsDate] DESC", cs);
```

Error Portion in you code :

```
SUBSTRING([AdsDesc],1,50) as AD.AdsDesc
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't have period symbol in column name alias:-

```
 SUBSTRING([AdsDesc],1,50) as AD.AdsDesc,
```

Change this to:-

```
 SUBSTRING([AD.AdsDesc],1,50) as AdsDesc,
```

Also, for such complex query you should create `stored procedure` instead.

Answer (score 0):

you have mistake here replace in your query from 
 `SUBSTRING([AdsDesc],1,50) as AD.AdsDesc` 
change to 
`SUBSTRING([AD.AdsDesc],1,50) as [AdsDesc]`

If it is not working then replace like this

```
 SELECT [AD.AdsID], [AD.Country], [AD.State], [AD.City], [AD.AdsTit],
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
  SqlDataAdapter dashowadsoneLogo = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT AD.[AdsID], AD.[Country], AD.[State], AD.[City], AD.[AdsTit], SUBSTRING(AD.[AdsDesc],1,50) as AD.AdsDesc,AD.[AdsPrice], AD.[Section],AD.[Category],AD.[Img1], AD.[AdsDate], I.[approv] FROM [ads] as AD JOIN UserInfo as I ON  AD.[Country] = @Location and I.[approv]='YES' ORDER BY AD.[AdsDate] DESC",cs);
```